# Session_start is not working properly through network and i got this error, how can i resolve this?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 php page the first one is "sample.php" and  the other is "survey.php". the problem is this when i run it in my local machine it is working fine but when i try it to open to another machine trough network it shows me this error.this error below shows in "sample.php" and below is my code for sample.php and survey.php..This error in sample.php and survey.php is like pointing in a session_start(), i don't know how to resolve it.can someone please help me resolve this.please..

**the image below is the error for sample.php**

[image]

**here is the code for sample.php**

```
<body bgcolor="black">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row header">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="image/header.png" class="img-responsive">
             <div id="login"><a href="#login-box" class="login-window">Login</a>        </div><!--End of Div login-->
        </div>
    </div>

     <div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
<a href="sample - Copy.php" class="close">Close</a>
 <form method="POST" class="signin" action="" name="Login">
    <fieldset class="textbox">
    <label class="username">
    <span>Username or email</span>
    <input id="username" name="user" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Username" required/>
    </label>
    <label class="password">
    <span>Password</span>
    <input id="password" name="pass" value="" type="password" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Password" required/>
    </label>
   <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>  
    </fieldset>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if(!empty($_POST['user']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pass=$_POST['pass'];

$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('region_survey') or die("cannot select DB");

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM survey_login WHERE username='".$user."' AND password='".$pass."'");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows!=0)
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$dbusername=$row['username'];
$dbpassword=$row['password'];
}

if($user == $dbusername && $pass == $dbpassword)
{
    //Code for alert message
    //after hitting ok redirect to TABLE.php
        //echo "<script>
        //alert('There are no fields to generate a report');
        //window.location.href='admin/ahm/panel';


session_start();

$_SESSION['username']=$user;

/* Redirect browser */
header('location:Survey.php');
}
} 
else {
    //header("Location: sample - Copy.php");
$message = "Invalid Username or Password";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
}
}
}
?>

</div><!--End of Pop up Login-->


    <div id="Slider">
        <div class="items">
            <center><img src="image/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></center>
         </div><!--End of Items-->

         <div class="items">
            <center><img src="image/2.jpg" class="img-responsive"></center>
         </div><!--End of items-->

         <div class="items">
            <center><img src="image/3.jpg" class="img-responsive"></center>
          </div>

          <div class="items">
            <center><img src="image/4.jpg" class="img-responsive"></center>
          </div>

          <div class="items">
            <center><img src="image/5.jpg" class="img-responsive"></center>
          </div>

          <div class="items">
            <center><img src="image/6.jpg" class="img-responsive"></center>
            </div>
    </div><!--End of Slider-->

    <!--Start of Footer-->
    <div class="row footer">
            <p>Copyright © 2015</p>
    </div><!--End of Footer-->

</div><!--End of Cotainer-Fluid-->
</body>
</html>
```

**and here is the error for survey.php**

[image]
[image]

**and this is the code for survey.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if(!$conn){
die("Error: ".mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("region_survey",$conn);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM municipality");
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!--<meta charset="UTF-8">-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Region 5 Survey</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="image/icon.ico"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<!--Datatables PLugin-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="datatable/media/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="datatable/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="datatable/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="datatable/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js">   </script>

</head>


<body bgcolor="black">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row header">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <img src="image/header.png" class="img-responsive">
            <div id="logout"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></div><!--End of Div login-->       
        </div>
    </div>



<div id="Session">
<?php
if (@$_SESSION['username'])
    echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']. "";
else
    header("location:sample - Copy.php");
?>
</div>

<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
<a href="Survey.php" class="close">Close</a>
<form method="POST" class="signin" action="" name="Add" target="iframe">
    <fieldset class="textbox">
    <label class="Province">
    <span>Province</span>
    <select name="province" class="textfields" id="province" onchange="populate(this.id,'municipality')">
        <option id="">Province</option>
        <option value="Albay">Albay</option>
        <option value="Camnorte">Camarines Norte</option>
        <option value="Camsur1">Camarines Sur 1</option>
        <option value="Camsur2">Camarines Sur 2</option>
        <option value="Catanduanes">Catanduanes</option>
        <option value="Masbate">Masbate</option>
        <option value="Sorsogon">Sorsogon</option>
    </select>
    </label>
    <label class="Date_Submitted">
        <span>Date Submitted</span>
            <input type="date" name="date" id="date" value="">
    </label>

    <label class="Survey_Number">
        <span>Survey Number</span>
            <input id="survey_number" name="survey_number" type="text" value="" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Survey Number">
    </label>
    <label class="Land_Type">
        <span>Land Type</span>
            <input id="land_type" name="land_type" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Land Type">
    </label>

    <label class="C-Size">
        <span>C-Size</span>
            <input id="c_size" name="c_size" value="" type="number" autocomplete="on" placeholder="C_Size" onKeyPress="return isNumber(event)">
    </label>
    <label class="Contractor">
        <span>Contractor</span>
            <input id="contrctor" name="contractor" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Contractor">
    </label>

    <label class="Module_Number">
        <span>Module Number</span>
            <input id="module_number" name="module_number" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Module Number">
    </label>
    <label class="Lad_Target">
        <span>LAD Target</span>
            <input id="Lad_Target" name="Lad_Target" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="LAD Target">
    </label>

    <label class="Fund_Year">
        <span>Fund Year</span>
            <input id="fund_year" name="fund_year" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Fund Year">
    </label>
    <label class="Land_Category">
        <span>Land Category</span>
            <input id="land_category" name="land_category" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Land Category">
    </label>
    <label class="Title_Number">
        <span>Title Number</span>
            <input id="title_number" name="title_number" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Title Number">
    </label>
     <label class="W_Bal">
        <span>W_Bal</span>
            <input id="w_bal" name="w_bal" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="W_Bal">
    </label>

    <label class="Lot_number">
        <span>Lot Number</span>
            <input id="lot_number" name="lot_number" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Lot Number">
    </label>
    <label class="Project_Number">
        <span>Project Number</span>
            <input id="proj_number" name="proj_number" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Project Number">
    </label>

    <label class="Agency">
        <span>Agency</span>
            <input id="agency" name="agency" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Agency">
    </label>
    <label class="Location">
        <span>Location</span>
            <select name="municipality" id="municipality" style="background:#666666; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:13px; height:30px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <option id="">Municipality</option>
            </select>
    </label>

    <label class="Date_Surveyed">
        <span>Date Surveyed</span>
            <input id="date_surveyed" name="date_surveyed" value="" type="date">
    </label>
    <label class="No_Lots">
        <span>Number of Lots</span>
            <input id="no_lots" name="no_lots" value="" type="number" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Number of Lots" onKeyPress="return isNumber(event)">
    </label>

    <label class="Area">
        <span>Area</span>
            <input id="area" name="area" value="" type="number" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Area">
    </label>
    <label class="LO_Name">
        <span>Land Owner Name</span>
            <input id="lo_name" name="lo_name" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Land Owner Name">
    </label>

    <label class="TimesRet">
        <span>Times Returned</span>
            <select name="times_ret" style="background:#666666; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:13px; height:30px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">---</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
            </select>
    </label>
    <label class="Times_resub">
        <span>Times Resubmitted</span>
            <select name="times_resub" style="background:#666666; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:13px; height:30px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">---</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
            </select>
    </label>

    <label class="Date_Ret1">
        <span>Date Returned 1</span>
            <input id="date_ret" name="date_ret" value="" type="date">
    </label>
    <label class="Date_Resub1">
        <span>Date Resubmitted 1</span>
            <input id="date_resub1" name="date_resub1" value="" type="date">
    </label>

    <label class="Date_Ret2">
        <span>Date Returned 2</span>
            <input id="date_ret2" name="date_ret2" value="" type="date">
    </label>
    <label class="Date_Resub2">
        <span>Date Resubmitted 2</span>
            <input id="date_resub2" name="date_resub2" value="" type="date">
    </label>

    <label class="Date_Ret3">
        <span>Date Returned 3</span>
            <input id="date_ret3" name="date_ret3" value="" type="date">
    </label>
    <label class="Date_Resub3">
        <span>Date Resubmitted 3</span>
            <input id="date_resub3" name="date_resub3" value="" type="date">
    </label>

    <label class="Date_Suspend">
        <span>Date Suspend</span>
            <input id="date_suspend" name="date_suspend" value="" type="date">
    </label>
    <label class="Date_Completed">
        <span>Date Completed</span>
            <input id="date_completed" name="date_completed" value="" type="date">
    </label>

    <label class="Station">
        <span>Station</span>
            <select name="station" style="background:#666666; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:13px; height:30px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">---</option>
            </select>
    </label>
    <label class="Date_Approved">
        <span>Date Approved</span>
            <input id="date_approved" name="date_approved" value="" type="date">
    </label>

    <label class="Date_Dar">
        <span>Date DAR</span>
            <input id="date_dar" name="date_dar" value="" type="date">
    </label>
    <label class="Date_PARO">
        <span>Date PARO</span>
            <input id="date_paro" name="date_paro" value="" type="date">
    </label>

    <label class="Cert_40">
        <span>Cert 40</span>
            <input id="cert_40" name="cert_40" value="" type="text" autocomplete="on" placeholder="Cert 40">
    </label>
    <label class="Date_Reported">
        <span>Date Reported</span>
            <input id="date_reported" name="date_reported" value="" type="date">
    </label>
    <br />

    <label class="Remarks">
        <span>Remarks</span>
            <textarea id="remarks" name="remarks" rows="10" cols="60" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;">
            </textarea>
    <br />

    <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit">Save</button> 
    <button id="submit" type="reset" name="reset">Reset</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<iframe src="about:blank" style="display:none" id="iframe" name="iframe"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
iframe.onload = function () { formSubmitResponse(iframe); };
function formSubmitResponse(iframe) {
var idocument = (iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document);
if(idocument) {
var responseFromBackend = idocument.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
}
}
</script>


</div>
<!--End-->
<div class="add_record">   
        <a href="export.php"><input name="image" type="image" value="download" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to download?');" src="image/Download.png" class="img-responsive" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
    </div>



<form action="delete.php" method="post">

<div class="add_record">   
        <input name="image" type="image" value="delete" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');" src="image/DELETE.png" class="img-responsive" width="40px" height="40px">
    </div>

<div class="add_record">
        <a href="#login-box" class="login-window"><input name="images" type="image" value="add" src="image/Add_record.ico" class="img-responsive" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
     </div>


     <div id="clear">
     </div>
    <hr>
    <br />



    <div id="datatable_wrapper">
        <table id="datatables" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>LO&nbsp;Name</th>
                    <th>Province</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Title&nbsp;Number</th>
                    <th>Lot&nbsp;Number</th>
                    <th>Survey&nbsp;Status</th>
                    <th>Survey&nbsp;Number</th>
                    <th>Project&nbsp;No</th>
                    <th>Module&nbsp;No</th>
                    <th>Area</th>
                    <th>Date&nbsp;Approved</th>
                    <th>Received&nbsp;by&nbsp;DAR</th>
                    <th>To&nbsp;PARO</th>
                    <th>Date&nbsp;Surveyed</th>
                    <th>Date&nbsp;Submitted</th>
                    <th>Ret1</th>
                    <th>Resub1</th>
                    <th>Ret2</th>
                    <th>Resub2</th>
                    <th>Ret3</th>
                    <th>Resub3</th>
                    <th>Fund&nbsp;Year</th>
                    <th>Remarks</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
    <?php
//Loop through the result set just as you would loop
//through a normal mysql result set
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['province_id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['municipality_name']; ?></td>
        <td><input name="selector[]" type="checkbox"
id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">&nbsp;
        <a href="update.php<?php echo '?id='.$row['id']; ?>">Edit</a></td>

    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
      </tbody>
   </table>
    </div>

</form>
    <!--Start of Footer-->
    <div class="row footer">
            <p>Copyright © 2015</p>
    </div><!--End of Footer-->

</div><!--End of Cotainer-Fluid-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP `session_start()` can start only before any thing is echoed out in the web page i.e anything outputs on webpage . Here are you are using a deprecated `mysql_*` functions so before session starts you are getting that error message. I recommend you to use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. For the time being you turn off warning message and error message in your page using the methods:

```
error_reporting(0); //or
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Comment: i can't figure out on how can i do that..can please help me?

Comment: at the start of your php page place this line of code `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` this will stop errors from displaying on your web page and session will then start.

Comment: should i do that in every page?

Comment: yes if do not want to see error message on your every page, but i do not recommend it to be done in development pages, on the live version you should do it.

Comment: ok, i will try it..but how about my error on session_start? how can i fix it?

Comment: @kierkier, that error is coming because the error message is coming, if that error message will stop once that error message on top stops coming.

Comment: but how can i do that?because if tried to put this code <?php
if (@$_SESSION['username'])
    echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']. "";
else
    header("location:sample - Copy.php");
?> on top it shows me an error..

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure PHP to not render E_DEPRECATED notices, or fix the deprecation notices. You should be using [mysqli](http://php.net/mysql) over mysql client.

No output can be sent back to the browser prior to the session starting.

Inside your php.ini

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Or in your script:

```
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

Comment: how can i convert that to mysqli? i have no idea..can you please help me convert it..